# PhD in Education - How competitive is it and what are admissions committees looking for?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, application

I currently have applications into several top tier education programs.  I am a bit worried about my chances.  I have about 7 years working in education, a unrelated masters and a masters in education.  My GPA in undergraduate was a 3.8 and in graduate school a 3.9 from a top 25 university.  I did well on the GRE verbal but poorly on GRE math.

Does anyone have any insight as to what they are looking for and what my chances are?  I read in another post to look for brutal honesty, so bring it on.

Comment: People with GPA over 3.7 are excellent.

Comment: Thanks so much @kitty.  I am still VERY concerned about my quantitative score.  Although I studied, I am not math-incliend and have been out of school for a long while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like, on the whole, you're in a pretty good place regarding your credentials. Have you checked out the Grad Cafe? The forums there are a fantastic resources for people in the process of applying.

Comment: I really appreciate your comment, Jacob. I have looked at Grad Cafe - thank you very much for that suggestion.  The unfortunate thing is that aren't too many people reporting on Education.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have good transcripts and a good GRA score (I'm doubting education majors need top math scores).

The brutal truth is admissions is a black box, and no one is assured a spot.  Grad Cafe is a good online research to vent anonymously.  You may want to ask around and see if there are others at your company who applied for grad school.  It can help tremendously to have a flesh-and-blood support group.

Comment: Thanks sevensevens!  I am definitely having a hard time grappling with lack of metrics and the "holistic process."